# New AbortController() returning empty object

Tags: react-native

I'm currently developing a react native application and I intend to use `AbortController` to cancel requests when necessary. The way I'm doing this is basically the simplest example available in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController), which is basically this:

```
const controller = new window.AbortController()
const signal = controller.signal

fetch(url, {signal})
```

However, for some reason, the creation of the `controller` object is not working properly, and if I `console.log` that object, I can see that it's being created as an empty object (`{}`).

But it gets weirder. If I use the `Debug` tool in react native dev tools, the `controller` object gets created as expected.

Any idea what might be the issue here?

Comment: yes but console.log(controller.signal.aborted) show the status of signal correctly ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

`AbortController` is part of the DOM spec, and not the ECMAScript Spec. This makes it a browser feature, not a JavaScript language feature. As a result, `AbortController` isn't something available by default with the JavaScript runtime that runs on a device.

When using the `Debug` tool, all JavaScript code runs within Chrome itself, communicating with native code via WebSockets. Chrome uses V8 as its JavaScript engine, which is a browser-based engine, and so has access to all of the DOM APIs - including `AbortController`. This is why you will see it working in `Debug` mode, as your JS code is being interpreted by V8, rather than the runtime on your device (likely JavaScriptCore, if you haven't enabled Hermes).

tl;dr - `AbortController` isn't part of the JS runtime on the device, so it won't work.